# Google Excel Date to Span two columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

```
2023                    
Jul                 
Tasks   Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed
ABC     01  02  03  04  05
                    
Reading                 
Music                   
Drawing
```

The above excel generates the monthly dates. Now for each of tasks in column 1 I need to have 2 columns under date as two people need to update the status. (ABC, DEF) types.

So each date has to span across two columns. The formula I am using for date generation is:

```
=LET(dt,DATE(A1,MONTH(A2&1),1),IF(LEN(A1),SEQUENCE(1,EOMONTH(dt,0)-dt+1,dt),))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of thinking it. One is to create a sequence of twice the amount of days, but adding "half a day" each time. Since you'll then format the cell as needed, the 12 hs will be despicable:

```
=LET(dt,DATE(A1,MONTH(A2&1),1),IF(LEN(A1),SEQUENCE(1,2*(EOMONTH(dt,0)-dt+1),dt,0.5),))
```

Other is to duplicate and get the array as a row:

```
=LET(dt,DATE(A1,MONTH(A2&1),1),
days,SEQUENCE(1,EOMONTH(dt,0)-dt+1,dt),
IF(LEN(A1),TOROW({days;days},,1),))
```

You could duplicate and sort, and other ways too!

Comment: What are "despicable" days?

Comment: Ha, a translation issue. I meant that if you format 02/03/2023 00:00 and 02/03/2023 12:00:00 as DD/MM/YYYY or any other format that does not include the time they'll look exactly the same @SolarMike

Comment: And I was actually talking about the 12 hours, not the days. You can say irrelevant, unimportant, insignificant, etc